# Angularjs : Show the count of new messages

Tags: angularjs

I am currently working on a Chat application and there I want to show the count of new messages.

```
    <div class="people"  >
        <div ng-repeat="user in allCompanyUsers">
            <div class="person" ng-click="activateChat(user); bubble=true" id="chat_{{user.id}}">
                <img alt="" />
                <span class="name" >{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
                <span ng-if="!bubble" class="noti_bubble">{{count}}</span></span> 
                <span class="preview"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="chat active-chat">
            <div ng-repeat="c in activeConversations track by c.time| orderBy:'time':false">
                <div class="bubble" ng-class="c.type">
                   {{c.message}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <span class="user_message">{{c.time | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated and thanks in advance...

Comment: what's the question ?

Comment: How to show the count of new message ?

Comment: you can just use `{{activeConversations.length}}`

Comment: Some JS would be helpful...

Comment: @svarog: To me it's not really clear if he wants to know how many messages are there in the chat altogether or if he wants to see how many new messages arrived since the last time the user was active (`[...] the count of new messages [...]`)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `{{activeConversations.length}}` in order to get the length/count as:

```
 <div class="people"  >
    <div ng-repeat="user in allCompanyUsers">
        <div class="person" ng-click="activateChat(user); bubble=true" id="chat_{{user.id}}">
            <img alt="" />
            <span class="name" >{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
            <span ng-if="!bubble" class="noti_bubble">{{activeConversations.length}}</span></span> 
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="chat active-chat">
        <div ng-repeat="c in activeConversations track by c.time| orderBy:'time':false">
            <div class="bubble" ng-class="c.type">
               {{c.message}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <span class="user_message">{{c.time | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```